# Long/High View with ScrollView in Xcode 7 for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, scrollview

First of all, sorry for the title, not sure what's the right name.

I'd like to create a long View in Xcode for a project (i'm doing it in storyboard). I'm using Swift (not Obj-C).

I'd like to display an imageView, some flexible (in height) labels, some buttons that in fact are longer then the ViewController in Xcode's storyboard.

I couldn't find any resource on how to achieve it. Somewhere I read that it's done by code, maybe I should do XIB? I'm pretty new to iOS development and I'm stuck.

What I'm trying to achieve is smth like this (image below, it's just a template from google search) but I'd like to have large image and lots of stuff beneath it:

[image]

How should I do it? Using swift? Some examples or resources will be very helpful.

**EDIT**

Just in case you found this question and you are also willing to find out how to do it I will tell you the best (but not easiest) way to build view like on the screenshot is Programatically. Yeah, the answer says Tableview, some might say XIB but after a long search I came up with the result that the best way is doing everything Programatically. If you do search for creating view controllers programmatically there are actually lots of great resources and most of developers advice you to do it programmatically as it gives you more control and flexibility. Also the rendering time is much less then using XIBs for example. As it turns out XIB-s are stored on the disk and it takes time to read them and render, and on the contrary, code runs much faster. I guess the eventual file size will be smaller too.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a `UIView` with a large height value embedded into a `UIScrollView`. The large view can then contain your other views within it (eg. ImageViews, Labels, ContainerViews).

Comment: @ZGski yeah, so are you telling me to put UIView inside UIScrollView and then put the rest? What if I don't know the exact height of labels as they will be dynamic. So what about the height of ScrollView and UIView? Shouldn't I set them to dynamic too? The rest is correct, i want high view with many elements inside.

Comment: Hi @mrGott. Are you able to provide any examples, demo or documentation to achieve this? :)  Lots of programmatic tutorials I have found seem to be very basic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the `UITableView` will be a better approach then`UIScrollView`

If your content is going to be static or constant in number of views then simply use a `UITableView` with static cells.
If your content will be dynamic i.e. dynamic number of rows depending on lets say JSON API response then dynamic cells with some coding in your ViewController

It will also help your requirement of dynamic heights of views e.g. labels since iOS 8+ supports `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` which can layout `UIView`s depending upon content automatically for you.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I'll definitely check it out and let you know if it was helpful, but now I have another question: if UITableView is a better approach, then why would we need ScrollView? What it would do better? Displaying images? I could take same approach (static table cells) for everything and ScrollView would be unused.

Comment: and one more thing, I'll face the same issue with UITableView static sell that I'm facing with ScrollView, the main problem is that I was trying to align UI Items using storyboard and I couldn't do that becuase the screen size displayed in storyboard is short and I need a heigher one to align all controlls <-- this is the real issue

Comment: If you mean that you need to be able to scroll that scrollview inside storyboard so you can do all the view building inside storyboard then you must know that static and dynamic `UITableView`s can be scrolled in storyboards. I have numerous such TableViews in my project. Using XCode 7.3

Comment: Just keep adding Cells to TableView and it will automatically start scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

yes do it with  XIB

first: make a nib file and change it's size to freedom , stretch it as u want and work there without putting any scroll view

second: open the storyboard and put the scroll view on your view controller there

third : in your viewController load the xib file and make the scrollView size equal to the xib file size like this :

```
//Outlets

@IBOutlet var scroller: UIScrollView!


//Variables 
let Aview = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("view", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? xibController

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.scroller.contentSize = CGSize(width: (Aview?.frame.size.width)!, height: (Aview?.frame.size.height)!)



    scroller.addSubview(Aview!)


}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but actually I switched to programmatically developing all apps and I don't have this kind of issues anymore.